# How to make my drop down list automatically choose the remaining ordered quantity on whatever store they choose

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I want in my cart page if I order 3 quantity of items example 3 wallets and user gets option to choose whichever store they want order to be fulfilled so if user chooses 1 store to fulfill 1 wallet and as soon as they click another store remaining 2 quantity of wallet so get choosen automatically.I want to do it using jquery .

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

View the .select() section of the JQuery API Documentation to allow auto-selection after etc. takes place

[HERE](https://api.jquery.com/select/)